# Is Discrete metric space proper?

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering about discrete metric space. Is it a proper metric space? I am trying to find some example of non proper metric space. I am not sure whether discrete metric space is proper or not.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be an infinite set equipped with metric $d(x,y)$ prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto 0$ if $x=y$ and $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto 1$ otherwise.

This metric induces the discrete topology on $X$.

$X$ is closed and bounded, but not compact.

This because $X=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$ where the singletons are open, and there is no finite subcover.

If I am well informed then a metric space is proper if every closed bounded subspace is compact.

If so then this metric space has been shown to be not proper.

Answer (score 0):

In a discrete metric space, any closed ball of radius $r < 1$ contains only one point, so it is compact. On the other hand, any closed ball of radius $r \ge 1$ coincides with the whole space, which is compact iff it is finite.

So, a discrete metric space is proper iff it is finite.

Comment: So if i have for example  n in N then the subset {1/n} of R is non proper??

Comment: @user319276 Yes, it is (though the metric is not strictly discrete, but equivalent). Even a simpler example: $\mathbb{N}$ with discrete metric.

Comment: But is N a complete metric space???

Comment: @user319276 Any discrete metric space is complete, since any Cauchy sequence has to be constant from some point.